# UIScrollView common for different viewControllers

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller

I had to have a tabBar with 9 tabs, so I added a Srollview(MHScrollViewController) with 9 buttons instead of tabBar. On click of each button, I add a viewController as subview to the Srollview.

In AppDelegate, have the following code:

```
MHScrollViewController *scrollViewController = [[MHScrollViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MHScrollView" bundle:nil];
scrollViewController.managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:scrollViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
```

Now say for one tab (button), I have added MHBikesViewController to MHScrollViewController as subView. In MHScrollViewController , I do this

```
bikesViewController = [[MHBikesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MHBikesView" bundle:nil];
bikesViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
bikesViewController.view.frame = baseViewiPhone.frame;
CGRect theFrame = bikesViewController.view.frame;
theFrame.origin.y = 0;
bikesViewController.view.frame = theFrame;
bikesViewController.navigationController = self.navigationController;
[baseViewiPhone addSubview:bikesViewController.view];
```

Now, I have two buttons on the MHBikesViewController page. When clicked, I want to push a new viewcontroller on MHBikesViewController. I am able to push, but the scrollView gets hidden under this viewcontroller.

Answer (score 2):

UINavigationController will cover all its contents with newly pushed controller anyway, so you need to take your scrollview with buttons outside of navigationcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

Beware of UIViewController parent/child relationships & responsabilities when designing UI.

A controller holds a main UIView, and all its subviews.
When adding this viewController's view into a more complex view hierarchy, this controller should then be the child of the viewController controlling this 'containement' UI.

Ask yourself : what IS your model for containment ?

9 tabs and some related content that occupy the rest of the screen?

Then in your case, `MHScrollViewController` is the daddy, it holds scrollable tabs and current viewController main view. It shouldn't be `UINavigationController` (which can be himself parent 'content' holding your `MHBikesViewController`)

Parent->Child containement in your case:

`MHScrollViewController` -> `UINavigationController` -> `MHBikesViewController`

Adding and removing child viewController is responsibility of the parent.

```
//(somewhere in MHScrollViewController.m or .h )
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *newContentController;
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIScrollView *tabsScrollView;

// method for pushing any 'tab' controller
// might be your UINavigationController
- (void)displayTabController:(UIViewController *)vc
{
    // remove previous controller
    if (self.contentController) {
        [self.contentController.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self.contentController removeFromParentViewController];
    } 


    //push the new controller, maintaining child/parent relationship
    self.contentController = newContentController;

    [self.view addSubview:contentController.view];
    [self.contentController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    // set frame  of contentController so that it stays above scrollView
    self.contentController.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height - self.tabsScrollView.bounds.size.height)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a tab bar with 9 tabs the standard way. It will automatically create a "more" tab. It might not be as slick as you wanted.